# Overloading generic implicit conversions

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I'm having a little scala (version 2.8.0RC1) problem with implicit conversions. Whenever importing more than one implicit conversion the first one gets shadowed. Here is the code where the problem shows up:

```
// containers
class Maybe[T]
case class Nothing[T]() extends Maybe[T]
case class Just[T](value: T) extends Maybe[T]

case class Value[T](value: T)

trait Monad[C[_]] {
  def >>=[A, B](a: C[A], f: A => C[B]): C[B]
  def pure[A](a: A): C[A]
}

// implicit converter
trait Extender[C[_]] {
  class Wrapper[A](c: C[A]) {
    def >>=[B](f: A => C[B])(implicit m: Monad[C]): C[B] = {
      m >>= (c, f)
    }

    def >>[B](b: C[B])(implicit m: Monad[C]): C[B] = {
      m >>= (c, { (x: A) => b } )
    }
  }

  implicit def extendToMonad[A](c: C[A]) = new Wrapper[A](c)
}

// instance maybe
object maybemonad extends Extender[Maybe] {
  implicit object MaybeMonad extends Monad[Maybe] {
    override def >>=[A, B](a: Maybe[A], f: A => Maybe[B]): Maybe[B] = {
      a match {
        case Just(x) => f(x)
        case Nothing() => Nothing()
      }
    }

    override def pure[A](a: A): Maybe[A] = Just(a)
  }
}

// instance value
object identitymonad extends Extender[Value] {
  implicit object IdentityMonad extends Monad[Value] {
    override def >>=[A, B](a: Value[A], f: A => Value[B]): Value[B] = {
      a match {
        case Value(x) => f(x)
      }
    }

    override def pure[A](a: A): Value[A] = Value(a)
  }
}

import maybemonad._
//import identitymonad._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(Just(1) >>= { (x: Int) => MaybeMonad.pure(x) })
  }
}
```

When uncommenting the second import statement everything goes wrong since the first "extendToMonad" is shadowed.

However, this one works:

```
object Main {
  implicit def foo(a: Int) = new  {
    def foobar(): Unit = { 
      println("Foobar")
    }   
  }

  implicit def foo(a: String) = new  {
    def foobar(): Unit = { 
      println(a)
    }   
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    1 foobar()
    "bla" foobar()
  }
}
```

So, where is the catch? What am I missing?

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: An aside note: I think `Nothing` should be a case object extending `Maybe`. Also you should consider choosing a different name for this case object as `Nothing` is already defined as the subtype of all types.

Comment: How about `case object None extends Maybe[Nothing]`? `None` too is already used in the standard library though (for exactly the same purpose.)

Comment: I should mention that this code will never go into production. It's just a testcase for myself to figure out some scala concepts ;)

Comment: Still those points are worth noting IMO. :)

Comment: Is it possible to demonstrate the problem in a shorter code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed bindings and imported bindings are shadowed by name. This applies equally to imported implicit conversions.

I believe that you could rename during the import as a workaround:

```
import IdentityMonad.{extendToMonad => extendToMonadIdentity}
import MaybeMonad.{extendToMonad => extendToMonadMaybe}
```

You may like to look at Scalaz, in particular `scalaz.{Functor, Scalaz, MA}` for another way to encode these type classes. In particular, when searching for a typeclass `Monad[X]`, the companion object `Monad` is searched.

Comment: The idea with renaming sounded good, but scala won't find both implicits after that.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the compiler regards

```
implicit object IdentityMonad extends Monad[Value]
```

as more specific than

```
implicit object MaybeMonad extends Monad[Maybe]
```

as part of the resolution process. There's an article posted by Daniel which covers this issue [here](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-implicits-to-select-types.html). With your second example, the calls resolve an implicit directly by type and the above resolution rule is not required.